# Aligning Angular ICON and HTML Text

Tags: html, angular, typescript, scss-lint

**Here is my HTML code**

```
<div class="transfer-link" *ngIf="showTransferLink" qa-name="transfer-link">
      <a routerLink="/Transfers">
        <mat-icon>sync_alt</mat-icon>
        <div>
          Transfer
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Here is my scss code**

```
 @media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 768px) {
        margin-top: 0.5rem;
        padding-top: 0.5rem;
        border-top: 1px solid $color-gray-light;
        flex-direction: row;

        div[role='button'] {
          flex-direction: row;

          .mat-icon {
            margin-right: 0.5rem;
            font-size: 1.5rem;
            height: 1.5rem;
            width: 1.5rem;
          }
        }
      }
```

I am trying to align my Icon next to my Transfer

[image]
**This is what I currently have**

---

[image]
**This is what I want to accomplish**

Comment: Add class to `<a routerLink="/Transfers">` and apply `display: flex; align-items: center`

Comment: **It does'nt wok**
```<div class="transfer-link" *ngIf="showTransferLink" qa-name="transfer-link">
      <a class="vertical-align" routerLink="/Transfers">
        <mat-icon>sync_alt</mat-icon>
        <div>
          Transfer
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```
**and add to your css**

```.vertical-align {
    display: flex; 
    align-items: center
}
```

Comment: Please create stackblitz to replicate your issue. **It does work for me**

Comment: how do I create a stackblitz?

Comment: Can you share the link?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-awnnnq?file=src/app/app.component.scss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<div class="transfer-link vertical-align" *ngIf="showTransferLink" qa-name="transfer-link">
      <a class="vertical-align" routerLink="/Transfers">
        <mat-icon>sync_alt</mat-icon>
        <div>
          Transfer
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and add to your css

```css
.vertical-align {
    display: flex; 
    align-items: center
}
```

Comment: try now, please